# How to format date columns in python

Tags: python, date

How do I properly define a date column?

I'm reading a csv file which contains a date column, and writing that out to an excel file.

Using pd.to_datetime I can get the values represented as datetime. However as my input is date only, the time values come out as zeroes.

I've tried using **format='%d/%m/%Y** however that fails as my input is not zero padded for the day and month values –

`ValueError: time data '07/18/2016' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y' (match)`

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, date

jobs_file = "test01.csv"
output_file = jobs_file.replace('csv', 'xlsx')

jobs_path = "C:\\Users\\Downloads\\" + jobs_file
output_path = "C:\\Users\\Downloads\\" + output_file

jobs = pd.read_csv(jobs_path,)

jobs['LAST RUN'] = pd.to_datetime(jobs['LAST RUN'])
#jobs['LAST RUN'] = pd.to_datetime(jobs['LAST RUN'], format='%d/%m/%Y')

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output_path, engine='xlsxwriter',
                        date_format='mm/dd/yyyy')

# Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
jobs.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Jobs', index=False)

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```

My input values look like this -

```
7/18/2016
```

Output is looking like this -

```
7/18/2016  12:00:00 AM
```

I'd like it to be just the date -

```
7/18/2016
```

Comment: Try `obs['LAST RUN'] = pd.to_datetime(jobs['LAST RUN'], format='%m%d/%Y')`

Comment: Try setting the `datetime_format` instead of `date_format` in `pd.ExcelWriter()`.